# Windows 10 cannot boot

Tags: windows-10, uefi, gpt, fixmbr

After reboot, my win10 stopped working, and just saying
Mbr error, press any key to boot from floppy

Please note that system disk is gpt

Neither of advices found in web do not work

Bootrec /fixboot says access denied
Bootrec /rebuildbcd finds windows installation in 
D:/windows 
But after pressing y on “add installation to boot list”
Just says that
The requesting system device cannot be found

Is there any detailed instructions on repairing this problem?

Comment: if system disk is gpt, then Windows must be booting in UEFI boot mode. And then MBR is not used other than to have one partition entry to say drive is gpt, so old MBR only tools do not think drive is blank and damage it. And if you are now trying to boot in BIOS mode, you may get a MBR error as it is and should not have any boot code. Make sure you have system set to boot in UEFI boot mode, maybe UEFI Secure Boot off.

Comment: See if any of these suggestions work for you>>>>>>https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/the-requested-system-device-cannot-be-found.html